# How to get the position of submatches in VBA?

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript, macros, ms-word

I need to get the index position value of submatched string. As per documentation, I have read through this [Regular expression](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html) and got to know `FirstIndex` property to get the position of matched string.

But this works only for one dimensional matched string. I couldn't apply `FirstIndex` for submatches.
Pls refer [sample matches](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=c10fb2e1)

I tried this format,

```
        Dim myRegExp As Object, match As MatchCollection            
        Dim matched As String
        Set myRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        myRegExp.pattern = find
        If myRegExp.test(text) = True Then
        Set match = myRegExp.Execute(text)          
        Debug.Print match(0).submatches(0) '' this is matched string
```

Where should I call `FirstIndex` to get position of submatched string

output:

```
match(0)=>Berry, Brent. (2006). What accounts for race and ethnic differences in  Berry, 
Brent. parental financial transfers to adult children in the United States? Journal of Family
Issues 37:1583-1604.   

submatches(0)=>Berry, Brent.
submatches(6)=>2006
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
submatches(0) at 0th position
submatches(6) at 16th position and so on
```

Comment: Are you looking for the index of the whole match? Just use `match(0).FirstIndex`. You do not need to even check `Submatches`.

Comment: No I need to get index of every submatched string

Comment: I have added more details in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't apply `.FirstIndex` to `SubMatches(x)` because it returns a `String`, not a `Match`. If the groups will return unique matches, you can find its location by simply using the `Instr` function:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = Find
    If .Test(text) Then
        Set match = .Execute(text)
        Debug.Print InStr(1, text, match(0).SubMatches(0)) '0
        Debug.Print InStr(1, text, match(0).SubMatches(5)) '16
        'and so on
    End If
End With
```

If the groups will *not* return unique results, you can track the position of the last match and loop through the results.  Note that `VBScript.RegExp` doesn't support look-behinds, so you don't have to take the length of the matches into account:

```
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = find
    If .Test(text) Then
        Set match = .Execute(text)
        Dim i As Long, pos As Long, found As String
        pos = 1
        For i = 0 To match(0).SubMatches.Count - 1
            found = match(0).SubMatches(i)
            pos = InStr(pos, text, match(0).SubMatches(i)) 
            Debug.Print found, pos
        Next
    End If
End With
```

Comment: What if there are multiple matches and the substring appears several times in the input string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That would match the behavior of `.FirstIndex`, although this does assume that the groups will return unique matches.

Comment: Even FirstIndex will return only first occurrence of matched string?

Comment: @Learning - Yep. It returns a `Long`, so it can *only* return one results - it returns the first.

Comment: Oh! So, If string has duplicates, which would be the effective way to get position of strings?

Comment: @Learning - It depends on the pattern.  For example, `(foo)(bar)?` can never have duplicate submatches.  If you're matching something like `foo` in "foobarfoobar", you'd get 2 *matches*, each with one submatch.  Note that if you have nested groups, i.e. `foo(b(az|ar))`, you would need to make the inner groups non-capturing with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

The [Submatches collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18(v=vs.84).aspx) contains strings:

> A SubMatches collection contains individual submatch strings, ...
>
> Each item in the SubMatches collection is the string found and
>   captured by the regular expression.

So you can't get the positions/indices.

Comment: Thank you ! I dint know this.